# Use Variable in Command Substitution

Tags: bash

I need some help with the following simple bash script, where the variable `i` does not seem to get substituted when running `curl` (causing an error).

(This is just a simple abstraction of the actual script)

```
for i in {1..3}
do
  HTML=$(curl -s 'http://example.com/index.php?id=$i')
done;
```

Comment: try enclosing in double quotes instead of single quotes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Variables are not substituted within single quotes. You have to use double quotes in this case:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    HTML=$( curl -s "http://example.com/index.php?id=$i" )
done
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html

> Enclosing a referenced value in double quotes (" ... ") does not
>   interfere with variable substitution. This is called partial quoting,
>   sometimes referred to as "weak quoting." Using single quotes (' ... ')
>   causes the variable name to be used literally, and no substitution
>   will take place. This is full quoting, sometimes referred to as
>   'strong quoting.'

A